# Google Photos backs up only cover photo from burst mode photos

Tags: backup, 7.0-nougat, google-photos, google-backup, motorola-moto-g5

When I take picture on my Moto G5 Plus, I long press in my Camera app to get multiple photos. From what I have read, it is called burst mode. The photos are stored in the `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera` folder. The naming convention of the image files goes something like this.

Cover photo - `IMG_YYYYMMDD_<SOME NUMBER>_BURST000_COVER.jpg`

Other photos - `IMG_YYYYMMDD_<SOME NUMBER>_BURST011.jpg`

But when the photos are backed up by Google Photos, only the cover photo gets backed up. I lost quite a few photos this way because I thought the auto backup will backup everything.

I cannot find any setting that can backup all the photos along with cover photo also. Is there any setting for this?

**Update 1:**

I have auto backup enabled.

**Update 2:**

Added details for image file naming convention and folder details.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below step

1. Open the Google Photos app.
2. On top left side click three line button.
3. Goto Setting.
4. Tap on Backup & Sync.
5. Now tap on Back up device folders.

Select the folders you want a backup.

Comment: The main photo and other photo gets saved in the same folder. But it seems Google only saves main photo.

Comment: I think the google photos app choose the best shot form multiple photos.

Comment: @RahulChokshi, step 5 is missing. what version you used?